# Data Transformation/ Paste in R

Tags: r, transformation, paste

Here is my colnames for my data frame.

```
colnames(new)[3:ncol(new)]
[1] "tag12" "tag13" "tag14" "tag15" "tag16" "tag17" "tag18" "tag22" "tag23"
[10] "tag24"
```

How do I create something like

new.1<- tag12 + tag13 + tag14......

Here is my first try.

```
for ( i in 3:ncol(all.1))
new.1<-as.data.frame(paste(colnames(all.1)[c(i-1)],colnames(all.1)[c(i)],sep="+"))

      paste(colnames(all.1)[c(i - 1)], colnames(all.1)[c(i)], sep = "+")
1                                                              tag3+tag4
```

Comment: This blog posy may be helpful: http://trinkerrstuff.wordpress.com/2013/09/15/paste-paste0-and-sprintf-2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just:

```
new.1 <- paste0( colnames(new)[3:ncol(new)], collapse="+")
```

If you give just one vector to `paste` or `paste0` you get a vector back with as many items as in the original vector. If you want to concatenate the items with "+" signs between them you need to us `collapse`.

Comment: I was thinking something else. Was doing it with the loop. Thanks

Comment: This is sort of vectorisation. Put a multi-item vector in and get a single element out.